# Is there a proof assistant supporting double negation modality?

Tags: double-negation, modality

Double negation modality is the modality corresponding to [double negation topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+negation#topology) in a topos, so it can be incorporated into type theory. I suppose this is an interesting way to embed classical mathematics into a constructive one. Search on the web turns out showing there are very few references on that. Is there any noticeable work done in this direction?

P.S. A common misunderstanding I've met for several time when talking about this is, double negation modality operator is **not** the operation that takes $P$ to $¬¬P$. It is the *sheafification* along the Lawvere-Tierney topology defined by $¬¬$, so these two operations only coincide in h-propositions.

P.P.S. Maybe relevant to [How does Prop relate to h-prop and double negation?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/how-does-prop-relate-to-h-prop-and-double-negation)

Comment: Would you accept double negation just for "small propositions" i.e. relative to a universe, or does it need to be all propositions?

Comment: You remind me of a subtle point. I think I've made assumption on impredicativity or propositional resizing so that every proposition is small in some sense. I have no idea what would happen if the type theory is predicative. But I am open to all answers with this or that assumptions or not.

Comment: I've been curious about how to internalize Lawvere-Tierney topology stuff in general. In my case I was thinking about boolean values as a subobject of Prop.

Comment: If you don't use the inductive nature of free sheaves, you don't gain much from sheafification except a bunch of technical issues with universes. Without univalence in the ambient theory, I currently don't know of an internal, constructive way to add universes to a sheaf-based theory. Meanwhile, the computational content of sheafification is trivial, it is but a free construction. So if your favourite type theory has a built-in universe of irrelevant propositions à la `SProp`, the stupid addition of an axiom `forall P : SProp, ~~ P -> P` will effectively result in something like sheaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice there's a slight mismatch between the title of the question and the content. I wrote the answer below about constructing the sheafification modality itself, but maybe what you want isn't the modality at all, but a way  to define the double negation sheaves without necessarily showing they are reflective. I think that kind of thing could be done in e.g. Coq, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with Coq to know how much it has been studied. If the aim is to formalise classical proofs in a constructive metatheory, it seems simplest to me to just postulate LEM.

In my opinion the best way to construct the double negation modality is to use homotopy type theory. By the general theory developed in Rijke, Shulman and Spitters, [*Modalities in homotopy type theory*](https://lmcs.episciences.org/6015), in particular section 3.3, we can construct the sheafification of a Lawvere-Tierney topology $j$ by nullifying all the $j$-dense propositions. The necessary higher inductive types are working in the latest version of Cubical Agda, and we can use the `HITs.Localization` module from the [standard Cubical library](https://github.com/agda/cubical) (they also have a module named `Nullification`, but the current version only accepts individual types, not families of types). The only weakness with this approach is that since Cubical Agda does not have propositional resizing, it's necessary to fix a universe level $\ell$, and only nullify up to that level, which is weaker than nullifying all propositions.

This gives the following Agda definition, which I've tested for Agda 2.6.2 with v0.3 of the Cubical library set as a default Agda library:

```
{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}

open import Cubical.Foundations.Prelude
open import Cubical.Foundations.Structure
open import Cubical.Foundations.HLevels

open import Cubical.Data.Empty
open import Cubical.Data.Unit

open import Cubical.HITs.Localization

module DoubleNegationSheafification {ℓ} where

¬¬-dense-props : Type (ℓ-suc ℓ)
¬¬-dense-props = Σ (hProp ℓ) (λ P → ((⟨ P ⟩ → ⊥) → ⊥))

maps-to-localize : (P : ¬¬-dense-props) → ⟨ fst P ⟩ → Unit
maps-to-localize _ _ = tt

DNSheafify : ∀ {ℓ'} → (Type ℓ') → Type (ℓ-max (ℓ-suc ℓ) ℓ')
DNSheafify = Localize maps-to-localize
```

Here are some other approaches that I found less satisfying:

- We can postulate the existence of sheafification or the HITs used to construct it in, I guess most proof assistants.
- If the law of excluded middle is provable, then the double negation modality trivially exists.
- If you work with setoids rather than types directly, then it's probably enough to just have inductive types rather than HITs.

Comment: I should have realized the HIT approach... I think I can do some experiments now.